# Hibernate 4.3.5 ignores v$session.program configuration property

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, database-connection, hikaricp

I previously used hibernate 3.2 and boneCP but I just upgraded to hibernate 4.3.5 and the Hikari connection pool to connect my java application to my oracle database. I set v$session.program to the program name I want and add it to the hibernate configuration.

I've created my own hibernate configuration class that extends the `Configuration` class provided by hibernate.

```
public class MyConfiguration extends Configuration {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public MyConfiguration() { }

    public MyConfiguration(SettingsFactory settingsFactory) {
        super(settingsFactory);
    }

    @Override
    public SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() throws HibernateException {
        ServiceRegistry registry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
        .applySettings(getProperties()).build();
        return new MySessionFactory(super.buildSessionFactory(registry));
    }
}
```

The `MySessionFactory` is a custom wrapper for the SessionFactory that does some magic via reflection with the persistenceContext field of the SessionImpl (that should be the problem though because it worked before the upgrade, too).

Then I call

```
Document configDocument = loadHibernateConfigruationDocument();
MyConfiguration conf = new MyConfiguration();
conf.configure(configDocument);
conf.buildSessionFactory();
```

However if I go to the database (while the application is running) and query

```
SELECT MACHINE, PROGRAM, USERNAME, count(*) as COUNT FROM v$session GROUP BY MACHINE, PROGRAM, USERNAME;
```

I can't find the program I just started. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I just added `hibernate.hikari.dataSource.v$session.program`and `hibernate.hikari.dataSource.v$session.username` to my configuration and everthing worked fine.