# Spring Boot 1.3.5 with Hikari Connection Pool not able to set program name in v$session

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, jhipster, hikaricp

I have a JHipster spring boot ver 1.3.5 application which connects to Oracle DB using Hikari Connection Pool. I am unable to set the program in `v$session` which should be possible by adding below in my application YAML

```
hikari:
   v$session:
     program: AppName
     username: DB_USER
```

I have tried adding these at spring.datasource level, datasource.hikari level and datasource level.

I also looked at [Hibernate 4.3.5 ignores v$session.program configuration property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24058144/hibernate-4-3-5-ignores-vsession-program-configuration-property) but that did not work as well.

**Update 1** - I tried all the below and none seem to work

```
spring.datasource.hikari.datasourceProperties.v$session.program AppName
spring.datasource.hikari.datasourceProperties.v$session.username    DB_USER
datasource.hikari.v$session.program AppName
datasource.hikari.v$session.username    DB_USER
datasource.hikari.datasourceProperties.v$session.program    AppName
datasource.hikari.datasourceProperties.v$session.username   DB_USER
hikari.v$session.program    AppName
hikari.v$session.username   DB_USER
hikari.datasourceProperties.v$session.program   AppName
hikari.datasourceProperties.v$session.username  DB_USER
```

Comment: Well that property doesn't exists for Spring Boot to do Hikari configuration so that indeed will not work. I would expect something like `spring.datasource.hikari.v$session.program` on the other hand to work. Or by prefixing it with `spring.datasource.hikari.datasourceProperties`.

Comment: @M.Deinum I tried the above (see Update 1) and none seem to work.

Comment: I am able to get it to work if I use HikariConfig (setDataSourceProperties) instead of Spring Boot DataSourceBuilder

Answer (score 2):

In Spring Boot 2 use:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    hikari:
      data-source-properties:
        "[v$session.program]": AppName
```

Answer (score 0):

Following works in Spring Boot 1.5.8.RELEASE using `application.yml` file:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    hikari:
      data-source-properties:
         v$session.program: AppName
```

Comment: Thank you! Finally a solution... spent a day on this.